# How listen for onload event for html tag with vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, vue-component

Consider a code:

```
<template >
    <div ref="messages" >
        <div v-for="message in thread" v-on:load="myLoad">
        <p class="chat-time">{{ message.message }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'MyName',
        methods : {
            myLoad() {
                console.log(`run`)
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

This does not work. But when I change `v-on:load` to `v-on:click` and start clicking I able to see `run` iun console.

Why `v-on:load` does not work?

**Important**

The question is about handling `load` event for html tag with vue. So adding `created()` or put `v-on:load` on to `<template>`
is not a solution.

Comment: Put simply, there is no `load` event for a div tag. You could trigger one manually I guess

Comment: Or you could add a `script` element immediately following the `div` element in question -- in all my experience the elements preceding the `script` elements would have been parsed and loaded (not necessarily their replaced content like images, stylesheets, video material etc) so you can access them as part of the document. The script element thus acts as a makeshift callback for a "loaded" event for any preceding node in the document. All that said, I'd be happily corrected if this contradicts standards compliant behavior -- haven't peeked into W3C/WHATWG publications on compliant behavior.

Comment: @amn interesting approach, did you post it as an answer somewhere (if one doesn't exist yet)?

Comment: @Kaddath No, I have not because I don't know much about Vue.js and I thought much of the point of using that framework was so that you don't have to solve the kind of problems outlined in the question -- in other words, there either exists an idiomatic Vue approach to solve the problem in the question, or there isn't but I wouldn't know. Hence a comment, not an answer. Also, my comment doesn't actually answer the question, it just elaborates on a way to access nodes in a document. In all regard this is arguably a case of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Vue Component and use the component instance lifecycle hooks like `created`

```
Vue.component('custom-comp', {
    props:['prop1','prop2'],
    template: '<div></div>',
    created: function () {
        alert('{{prop1}} created.');
    },
    methods: {}
});
```